# How to manually run Windows Update for Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I'd like to manually run Windows update without accessing the Windows update web site. Could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start menu -> Programs -> All Programs -> Windows Update

But that will still just open IE to the web site.  The only other way to do it is to read through reams of ms knowledge base articles for Server 2003 to find everyone one that includes a windows update download, cross reference that for updates that are already installed on yoru computer, and download each update from microsoft's download site and install it by hand.  It'd take you a year or more to finish.

Perhaps we could do a little better if we understood your motivation for the request.

**Update**
As I think about, the windows update site works by running an ActiveX control.  You might be able to build another program that hosts this control, but I doubt it.  And even if you did, the control would still need to connect to Microsoft's windows update site to download the patches.

Comment: Is there a way to get the windows update control panel?  I was able to get to it once when patches were pending, but when patches are not pending there's nothing there.  I wish to enable "auto update" as IE and port 80 are blocked on this computer.

Comment: @Bryce If you're still running 2003, it's moot. THERE ARE NO NEW UPDATES RELEASED FOE SERVER 2003. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it, and upgrading this server is job one. If you're not using 2003, then everything is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MBSA to do it, its kind of a pain but it can be used to install updates one at a time.

v2.2  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923.aspx

v2.3  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7558

.

There is also this program, it will download all the updates for a variety of MS products, compile them into an ISO, then you can burn this do disc, use the disc to update the PC automatically.

http://www.wsusoffline.net/

.

Comment: It's in top: http://alternativeto.net/software/wsus-offline-update/

Answer (score 1):

There's a 3rd-party tool called [autopatcher](http://www.autopatcher.net/forum/), which I've used for years while doing computer repair.  Basically, it downloads all the updates you need after the latest service pack, allows you to pick and choose what you want, then allows you to install them.  The hotfixes themselves are downloaded from microsoft through the application.

Answer (score 0):

Those for the nine-and-a-half years from January 2006 are available for download from Microsoft as monthly [Security Releases ISO image](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/913086/security-updates-are-available-on-iso-9660-dvd5-image-files-from-the-microsoft-download-center) files. These run from that date till the last one in July 2016, after support for Windows Server 2003 ended the previous year.

These monthly files provide a way to apply the updates without connecting the machine in question to the internet, and in sizeable chunks too, meaning far less manual effort—at least for that nine-and-a-half year period. Other updates can be downloaded individually from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows%202003%20security) for applying offline.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to change update settings (but no see past updates), it's in the Windows Server 2003 control panel under "Auto Update Settings"